# Pod install fails for Flutters video_editor example

Tags: xcode, flutter, ffmpeg

I am able to clone and run flutter video_editor  https://github.com/seel-channel/video_editor
in  both  the  iPhone and Android
.

However, if I copy its example part, it works in  Android but not on iPhone (physical). Ipod install fails.  Please see attached screenhsot.

I am using all the same versions of everything, for the example part as well as the clone part.

Podfile
platform :ios, '9.3'

pubsec.yaml
video_editor:
path: ^1.8.0
helpers: ^1.1.1
image_picker: ^0.8.4
video_player: ^2.2.6

macOS Monterey
version 12.1
xCode version 13.1

[image: Android Studio Error]
[image: xCode error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's work for me.

I download example from video editor.

Then in pubspec.yaml file I changed following

```
  # video_editor:
  #   path: ../
  video_editor: ^1.2.2
```

Then I fire command `flutter pub get` and `pod install` it's getting same error you want.

Then after I change `platform :ios, '9.3'` to `platform :ios, '12.1'` in pod file and changed deployment info `9.0` to `12.1` in target(Like below image) then fire commane `pod install` and it's work fine.

[image]

Comment: I am still getting the same error, can you upload your code to github (public) which I can clone? Thanks a ton for all your help so far!

Comment: I upload the code in https://gitlab.com/ChiragKothiya1996/video-editor

Comment: I am not able to clone it, it is asking me to Add Configuration in AndroidStudio, which I am  not familiar with, besides the example part is not implemented standalone and is wrapped inside the main video_editor package, which in any case works for me (the original one).

Comment: Hi Chirag, is it possible we have a chat and perhaps watch my screen as I try to create the example part, just to ensure I am following the steps correctly?

Comment: yes of course, where we can chat?

Comment: Thank you Chirag for your nice gesture, quick responses and help. The issue got resolved automatically, may be some build clean was required.

Comment: Wow great @AzazSayed